# How to split a dataframe into chunks and merge horizontally every time index starts over

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that is actually multiple dataframes concatenated vertically. I'd like to merge them horizontally but I'm having trouble splitting it up by the index value. I'd like to start a new chunk where the index is 'finish', and I want to avoid doing this manually as the actual dataframe has about 20 sections, and each section is not the same length.

This is the original dataframe.

```
        12_boys  12_girls
finish                   
1        Team A    Team A
2        Team B    Team B
3        Team C    Team C
4        Team D    Team D
5        Team E    Team E
finish  14_boys  14_girls
1        Team A    Team A
2        Team B    Team B
3        Team C    Team C
4        Team D    Team D
finish  16_boys  16_girls
1        Team A    Team A
2        Team B    Team B
3        Team C    Team C
4        Team D    Team D
```

This is what I'd like to have.

```
       12_boys 14_boys 16_boys 12_girls 14_girls 16_girls
finish                                                   
1       Team A  Team A  Team A   Team A   Team A   Team A
2       Team B  Team B  Team B   Team B   Team B   Team B
3       Team C  Team C  Team C   Team C   Team C   Team C
4       Team D  Team D  Team D   Team D   Team D   Team D
5       Team E     NaN     NaN   Team E      NaN      NaN
```

The closest I can come up with is splitting and merging manually, but this doesn't transpose the column names.

```
data1 = data.iloc[0:6]
data2 = data.iloc[6:10]
data3 = data.iloc[11:15]
data_merge = pd.merge(data1, data2, on='finish', how='outer')
data_merge = pd.merge(data_merge, data3, on='finish', how='outer')

Output:

    12_boys_x   12_girls_x  12_boys_y   12_girls_y  12_boys     12_girls
finish                      
1   Team A  Team A  Team A  Team A  Team A  Team A
2   Team B  Team B  Team B  Team B  Team B  Team B
3   Team C  Team C  Team C  Team C  Team C  Team C
4   Team D  Team D  Team D  Team D  Team D  Team D
5   Team E  Team E  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
finish  14_boys     14_girls    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can first identify the groups by checking where the index changes to `finish`. Then we use `GroupBy` and `pd.concat` to concat each group next to each other:

```
grps = (df.index == 'finish').cumsum()

dfs = []
for grp, dfg in df.groupby(grps):
    if grp != 0:
        dfg.columns = dfg.iloc[0].values
        dfs.append(dfg)
    else: dfs.append(dfg)

df_new = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, sort=False).iloc[:-1]
```

```
  12_boys 12_girls 14_boys 14_girls 16_boys 16_girls
1  Team A   Team A  Team A   Team A  Team A   Team A
2  Team B   Team B  Team B   Team B  Team B   Team B
3  Team C   Team C  Team C   Team C  Team C   Team C
4  Team D   Team D  Team D   Team D  Team D   Team D
5  Team E   Team E     NaN      NaN     NaN      NaN
```